# Compare objects within Array and put equal values in seperate new object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In my App I have an array of objects 'class: EventObjects' with several properties like 'date: NSDate?' and 'stuffToDo: String?' that are fetched from a calendar database. What I try to achieve now is putting all EventObjects with the same date property together in another object of 'class: EventsAtSameDate'.

```
class EventsAtSameDate: NSObject
{
   var date:NSDate?
   var eventObjects:NSArray<EventObject>?
}
```

And finally have a nested array with the EventsAtSameDate.

```
var nestedArrayOfEventsAtSameDateObjects: Array<EventsAtSameDate>?
```

I know how to search and sort an array with .filter .sort .sortInPlace etc. functions. But how can I compare the dates in the array with each other and put them in another nested Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instantiate a dictionary to keep track of the dates present while doing one iteration over the initial array of type `EventObject`. Then iterate the the dictionary to instantiate classes of `EventsAtSameDate` and append them to the `nestedArrayOfEventsAtSameDateObjects: [EventsAtSameDate]`

The code would look something like:

```
var nestedArrayOfEventsAtSameDateObjects = [EventsAtSameDate]()

//instantiate a dictionary that uses Date as the key and an array of EventObject as the associated value
var dictionary = [Date: [EventObject]]()

//iterate through your intial array of EventObjects
for obj in eObjs {
    //check if you have already seen the date in the collection
    if dictionary[obj.date] != nil {
        //if you have - then append it to that date
        dictionary[obj.date]?.append(obj)
        continue
    }
    //otherwise, add it to the dictionary for a check later in the loop
    dictionary[obj.date] = [obj]
}


//then iterate through the dictionary

for (date, eObjs) in dictionary {
    if eObjs.count > 1 {
        let sameDate = EventsAtSameDate()
        sameDate.date = date
        sameDate.eventObjects = eObjs
        nestedArrayOfEventsAtSameDateObjects.append(sameDate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would sort the array of your events by date and then iterate over them. Check if the date is newer then the previous one and create another storage if so.

```
class Event {
    var date:Date!
}

class EventsList
{
    var date:Date!
    var events:[Event]!
}

func createEventsLists(sortedEvents: [Event]) -> [EventsList] {
    guard sortedEvents.count > 0 else { return [] }

    var currentEventList = EventsList()
    var result = [currentEventList]
    var lastDate = sortedEvents.first!.date

    for event in sortedEvents {
        let newDate = event.date.compare(lastDate!) != .orderedDescending
        if newDate {
            currentEventList = EventsList()
            result.append(currentEventList)
        }
        currentEventList.events.append(event)
        lastDate = event.date
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: That could also work. In my case the hint with the Dictionary from syllabix solved my problem. Thanks.